# Don't display item in templatefield in filtering

Tags: templatefield

I have a gridview with templatefield . I fill gridview in page load .

**The problem is when filtering gridview , items in templatefield don't display .**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `filtering gridview` means search and display result.The GridViewSearch control is an ASP.NET user control that provides `search/filtering` capabilities which can then be used to filter a `DataTable/DataSource` bound to a GridView control.You see example here.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16781/GridView-Search-Control